# Is an extra navigation controller required for every succeeding view controller with bar button items?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm not having any technical troubles but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this *in interface builder*, considering adding a new nav controller looked repetitive and unnecessary. When I add another view controller to the nav hierarchy (through a Show segue), and then try to add  a bar button item, I can't until I embed the view controller in a new nav controller. Here's what I mean:

Unable to add Bar Button Item:

[image: Without new nav controller]

Able to add Bar Button Item:

[image: Only with new nav controller]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to embed each view controller into its own nav controller. For each view controller down the line of one navigation controller, drag a **Navigation Item** onto the navigation bar. You can then add bar button items and a title.

---

[image]